# Change ValidationPipe errors from NestJS + GraphQL

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

Just posting here the workaround that I found in GitHub to change the NestJS Validation errors. I was trying to format the errors and include the field names.

I spent a lot of time in NestJS docs, googling and reading GitHub issues until I found this one, with a perfect answer (for now, as I see that it's something not developed yet in NestJS in an easy way).

Answer (score 1):

The full workaround (and the discussion) you can find here:
https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/1053#issuecomment-786972617

There are other useful (and simple) solutions in this thread. ;)